# Where to instantiate class in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to use the `aws-sdk-comprehend` gem in my model `Metric`, but I'm not sure if it's ok (accordingly to rails convention) to instantiate outside of the class, e.g:

```
comprehend = Aws::Comprehend::Client.new

class Metric < ApplicationRecord
  def key_phrases
    # Use comprehend object here.
  end
end
```

Is there a rule of thumb to in regard to this situation? I don't want to instantiate in the key_phrases because it will instantiate every time I call it.

Comment: It's perfectly fine to instantiate another object inside of an AR class. In fact AR does this already with it's relationships (has_many/belongs_to/has_one). If there's overhead for initializing `Aws::Comprehend::Client` though, and its instance can be used throughout your application with just one config, you may want to consider memoizing it in an initializer and a global, or in `application.rb`

Comment: @JoshBrody I thought about memoizing it. Is there a Gem that you recommend?

Comment: What's wrong with an instance method `comprehend_client` that memoizes the client? Then call the object from `key_phrases` with `comprehend_client`?

Comment: @AmandaFerrari `def comprehend_client; @comprehend_client ||=  Aws::Comprehend::Client.new; end`

Answer (score 0):

The answer was already posted in the comments. Here a full example of how it might look in idiomatic Ruby:

```
class Metric < ApplicationRecord
  def key_phrases
    # Use comprehend object here.
    comprehend_client
  end

  private

  def comprehend_client
    @comprehend_client ||= Aws::Comprehend::Client.new
  end
end
```

Comment: One big reason you want to do this instead of referencing a local variable in the outer scope is that it lets you use setter injection to mock the dependency in tests.